# Thermodynamics equation that involves time?

Tags: thermodynamics

There are principles in thermodynamics—e.g., that heat transfers from hot to cold—and equations like $$Q=mc\Delta T,$$ but is there any equation in thermodynamics related with time?

Comment: Thermodynamics is a theory of homogeneous systems near their thermodynamic equilibrium, which is only possible if time scales for state transitions are (nearly) infinitely long. One can make an ad-hoc theory called non-equilibrium thermodynamics which tries to incorporate first and higher order deviations from this, and that theory has time in it. In practice it's neither particularly useful nor easy to deal with, though, because systems out of equilibrium rarely function the way it predicts.

Comment: Thermodynamics deals with time averages for the most part. However, time does play a role in non-equilibrium statistical mechanics. See, for example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_equation

Answer (score 4):

The area of Transport Phenomena deals with momentum transfer in solids and liquids (fluid- and solid mechanics), heat transfer, and mass transfer (diffusional).  In freshman physics, you learned about the rate of conductive heat transfer along a rod from the hot end to the cold end, and learned it is related to the thermal conductivity of the rod.  In a sense, this is a time-dependent process, because it enables you to calculate the cumulative amount of heat transferred from one end of the rod to the other.  More advanced versions of this discipline involve transient heating of a rod or slab, where the time- and space-dependent variations of the temperature within the rod are determined, starting from an initial state and going to a final state.  Similar time-dependent methodology can be applied to momentum transfer (e.g. viscous momentum transfer in fluids), and transient diffusion in solids and liquids.  Transport Phenomena have been used extensively and successfully in engineering (particularly chemical engineering) for hundreds of years.